# Cannot access Microk8s service from browser using NodePort service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, microk8s

I installed microk8s on my ubuntu machine based on steps here https://ubuntu.com/kubernetes/install#single-node

Then I followed kubernetes official tutorial and created and exposed a deployment like this

```
microk8s.kubectl create deployment kubernetes-bootcamp --image=gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1

microk8s.kubectl expose deployment/kubernetes-bootcamp --type=NodePort --port 8083
```

This is my `kubectl get services` output

```
akila@ubuntu:~$ microk8s.kubectl get services
NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes            ClusterIP   10.152.183.1    <none>        443/TCP          25h
kubernetes-bootcamp   NodePort    10.152.183.11   <none>        8083:31695/TCP   17s
```

This is my `kubectl get pods` output

```
akila@ubuntu:~$ microk8s.kubectl get pods
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kubernetes-bootcamp-6f6656d949-rllgt   1/1     Running   0          51m
```

But I can't access the service from my browser using `http://localhost:8083` OR using `http://10.152.183.11:31695`

When I tried http://localhost:31695 I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

How can I access this "kubernetes-bootcamp" service from my browser ?
Am I mising anything ?

Comment: You should access application using  ```http://localhost:31695```

Comment: @DashrathMundkar I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The IP `10.152.183.11`  is `CLUSTER-IP` and not accessible from outside the cluster i.e from a browser. You should be using `http://localhost:31695` where `31695` is the `NodePort` opened on the host system.

The container of the `gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1` image need to listen on port `8083` because you are exposing it on that port. Double check that because otherwise this will lead to `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

If the container is listening on port `8080` then use below command to expose that port

```
microk8s.kubectl expose deployment/kubernetes-bootcamp --type=NodePort --port 8080
```

Comment: I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: that image what app does it have ? Does it listening on port 8083?

Comment: you are correct. It was listing to 8080. when I exposed port 8080 I could load the page

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
kubectl port-forward <pod_name> <local_port>:<pod_port>
```

then access `http://localhost:<local_port>`