# Ubuntu: Cannot access Kubernetes service from outside cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I am new to K8s, and I am facing issues trying to connect to K8s NodePort service from outside the cluster.

I am unable to load the nginx default page when I try accessing it from my local machine using the URL: http://localhost:31008

I understand this is a common problem and I referred the below solutions,

[Cannot access NodePort service outside Kubernetes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66212319/cannot-access-nodeport-service-outside-kubernetes-cluster)

[Cannot access Microk8s service from browser using NodePort service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62918016/cannot-access-microk8s-service-from-browser-using-nodeport-service)

However none of them are working for me.

Any guidance on this issue would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Setup:

Server OS: Ubuntu Server on AWS

K8s: minikube

Below is my deployment YAML:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: front-end
      name: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      name: nginx
      labels:
        app: front-end
        name: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
```

Below is my Service YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: front-end
    name: nginx
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 31008
```

Below is the output of the command `kubectl get all`,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in the target port config as **Nginx** run on default port **80**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: front-end
    name: nginx
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 31008
```

The **target port** should be `80`

Config of Nginx :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-nginx
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Ref document : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/

Comment: I changed the port numbers according to the above reply and I still can't access the service from my browser.

Comment: How you are tring to access the service ? What you are passing in browser?

Comment: I am browsing this URL : http://localhost:31008.

Comment: try using the IP local machine or node once with port

Comment: nopes... didn't work.

Comment: check your pod running or not ?

Comment: Pods are running, and if I execute a curl from within the pod, then I can see the nginx welcome page.

Comment: change the port 8080 to 80 also and test once please also in your service labels are properly set

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using docker + minikube and facing the above problem, the solution is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53105856/1773169).